# How to insert 01-JAN-13 12.00.00 AM in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using the following query

```
insert into Employee (First_name, Last_name, Salary, Joining_date, Department) 
values ('John', 'Abraham', '1000000', cast('2013-01-13 12:00:00.000' as  datetime), 'Banking')
```

Finally I used cast for that temporary work. But now I need to insert that format.

Comment: Don't store formatted dates in database. Do the formatting in Application layer or while it is displayed

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Why do you need to cast that as a datetime? Also 12:00:00 is midday, not midnight. If you want midnight you'll need 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Unseparated format : (this assumes that Joining_date is of type Date or DateTime)

```
insert into Employee (First_name,Last_name,Salary,Joining_date,Department) 
values ('John','Abraham','1000000', '20130113 12:00:00','Banking')
```

Also look at this : http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes